# .bashrc file is looping "script" command

Tags: bash, shell, autostart

I'm trying to set up a little shell script using the linux command "script" to log every input on my Kali Linux machine.

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y_%H:%M:%S")
script /root/Logs/log_$now.txt
```

The script itself seems to work but i want to add it to the bash autostart, so whenever i open a terminal, my shellscript gets executed.

I tried adding it to my .bashrc file but when I open a terminal now, the script gets looped.
I added a simple "echo 'test'" script and it only starts once on terminal launch.
Adding the script to my .profile file and executing .profile manually works as intended, but as soon as i enter a script using the "script" command to my .bashrc, it gets looped.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you figured how to do it ? I have the same idea. Using hint about setting SCRIPT variable solve recursion problem, but in my case log file is created, but it stays empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A new terminal window is *one* way of starting a new interactive shell, but so is running `script`. You only want to run `script` in the first case, not in *every* case.

`script` itself sets a variable in the environment to let you know if you are already in a shell started by `script`. Check for that variable before trying to run `script` again.

```
if [[ -z $SCRIPT ]]; then
    now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y_%H:%M:%S")
    script /root/Logs/log_$now.txt
fi
```

The value of `SCRIPT`, if set, is the name of the file being logged to.

Alternatively, you can configure your terminal emulator to run `script` directly, rather than having it continue to open an ordinary interactive shell and you trying to alter *its* configuration.

---

The above applies to BSD `script`; for GNU `script`, you'll have to set such a variable yourself.

```
if [[ -z $SCRIPT ]]; then
  now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y_%H:%M:%S")
  export SCRIPT=/root/Logs/log_$now.txt
  script "$SCRIPT"
fi
```

Comment: I like your idea, but script doesnt seem to set any environmental variables on start in my case

Comment: Hm, that seems to be a BSD-specific feature not implemented in GNU `script`. You can set a variable yourself before starting `script`; I'll update the answer.

Comment: Strange things. This hint help me avoid recursion... but now, script create session/log file, but this file stays empty.

Answer (score 2):

The script(1) command opens a new interactive shell.

The file `.bashrc` runs on every interactive bash shell that is started, hence your infinite recursion.

If you want something to run only on the login shell, you put it into `.bash_profile`.

This should avoid the infinite recursion.

Comment: The reason is correct, but I don't think putting the command in `.bash_profile` is correct. The goal seems to be to use `script` each time a new terminal window is opened. The solution may be to adjust how the terminal runs its initial command, rather than changing how any interactive shell starts.